# CSS Bootstrap: Auto resize input field and button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a a text type input field, and I have a button for "Search".  I would like these 2 objects to be horizontally aligned; with the button being as big as it wants to be, and the input field taking up the rest of the space.  I have been trying with CSS all day, but with no avail.

I am using RoR, and employing the Bootstrap library.  I was wondering if there was anything out of the box that would make this work.  I have also tried using flexboxes, but the input field seems to have a mind of its own.  Below is the problematic code.

```
<div class="mini-layout fluid">
 <div class="mini-layout-body">
   <h2>Shows</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="mini-layout-sidebar">
   <div class="search_container">
      <input id="search_shows_text" type="text" class="search-query">
      <button id="search_shows_button" 
          type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've been able to get the search_container class to lay things out horizontally, but getting its children to resize appropriately has managed to escape me all day.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**  Thanks to Krishnan and the SO community I got the solution working.  Below is the code for anyone else.

HTML
    
       
           
           Search

**CSS**

```
.search_container
{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.text_area
{
  width: 55%; //Change as per your requirement
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

.but_area
{
   width: 25%; //Change as per your requirement
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: could you add a fiddle to your question, so we can see the problem in action?

Comment: bootply.com is a good place to put this

Comment: @FlexField By default bootstrap set its input field size to some predefined value. You can override it to make your input field to accomodate your needs.

Comment: @VijayRamamurthy Thanks Vijay, I will keep that in mind and make use of this bootply resource !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bootstrap have width set to **206px** for text area and **71px** for submit button. So in order to make it accomodate your requirements you have to override those default properties. I would probably do something like this.

create a class **text_area with custom property**

```
.text_area
{
   width: 85%; //Change as per your requirement
}
```

create a class **but_area with custom property**

```
.but_area
{
   width: 10%; //Change as per your requirement
}
```

And would use it in input text area and button.

```
 <input id="search_shows_text" type="text" class="search-query text_area">
  <button id="search_shows_button" 
      type="submit" class="btn btn-primary but_area">Search</button>
```

It will make my **text area to occupy 85% of the space** and **button to occupy 10% space** in my window and remaining 5% of space is left free.

Comment: @Amaranth Krishnan That was a good enough answer to get me on the ground to where I could march my way to a solution in a few minutes.  Here is the actual working html/css if anyone else stumbles up the same problem.